# Fibonacci Series with long numbers php

Tags: php

I am making Fibonacci series for long numbers in PHP. For example my n = 100 and post 92 sequence it starts getting values like 1.2200160415122E+19.

Please help me to understand how to handle such big numbers in PHP.

Comment: That is scientific notation for `1.22 x 10^19`. Here is a [floating point bible](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

On first sight I'd say this has nothing to do with the php language. It is a general issue with floating point notation that you simply do not have a precision as with fixed point notation. For tasks like Fibonacci I'd say you need a precision of 1, thus a floating point notation is unsuitable for the task. No way around that.

However there are a number of classes and extensions for php that allow arithmetic with large integers. I suggest you take a look into those:

- [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)
- [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php)